# Error showing as "Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details."

Tags: java, aggregation, composition

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Dental{
    public Vector Sroomlist;
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public int contact;
    
    public Dental(String name, String address, int contact){
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.contact = contact;
        Sroomlist = new Vector();
    }
    public void addsrooms(Sroom room){
        Sroomlist.addElement(room);
    }
  public void Details(){
      System.out.println("DENTAL SURGERY DETAILS");
      System.out.println("____________________");
      System.out.println("Name: "+name);
      System.out.println("Address: "+address);
      System.out.println("______________");
      System.out.println("Contact: "+contact);
      System.out.println("SURGERY ROOM DETAILS");
      int n = 0;
      while (n<Sroomlist.size()){
          Sroom room = (Sroom)
          Sroomlist.elementAt(n);
          n +=1;
          
}
      } 

 public class Sroom {
    public int r_id;
    public String type;
    
    public Sroom(int r_id, String type){
        this.r_id = r_id;
        this.type = type;
 }
    public void SRoomDetails(){
        System.out.println("Room ID: ");
        System.out.println("Room Type: ");
 }
 }
public class Composition {
    public void main(String[]args){
        Dental d = new Dental ("Dental Surgery ", "abc road",11889796);
        Sroom sr1 = new Sroom (1," Surgery Room 01");
        Sroom sr2 = new Sroom (2," Surgery Room 02");
        Sroom sr3 = new Sroom (3," Surgery Room 03");
        Details();
        
        d.addsrooms(sr1);
        d.addsrooms(sr2);
        d.addsrooms(sr3);
        d.Details();
    }
 }
}
```

```
    public String type;
    
    public Sroom(int r_id, String type){
        this.r_id = r_id;
        this.type = type;
 }
    public void SRoomDetails(){
        System.out.println("Room ID: ");
        System.out.println("Room Type: ");
 }
 }
public class Composition {
    public void main(String[]args){
        Dental d = new Dental ("Dental Surgery ", "abc road",11889796);
        Sroom sr1 = new Sroom (1," Surgery Room 01");
        Sroom sr2 = new Sroom (2," Surgery Room 02");
        Sroom sr3 = new Sroom (3," Surgery Room 03");
        Details();
        
        d.addsrooms(sr1);
        d.addsrooms(sr2);
        d.addsrooms(sr3);
        d.Details();
    }
 }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaro8.png)

This the error showing. I am beginner and cannot understand this error

I try to develop a dental surgery system for my project. while developing I got many error but I solved that all. My project deadline is 23/11/2022. But today I get this error and I totally Frustrated. I have upload code and image of the error here. please can you give me a immediate solution for this error?

Comment: That is not an error, but a note. It advices you to use Generics and other features being introduced with Java 6 (if I remember correctly). Specifically the use of Vector is discouraged, it should be replaced by List<Dental>

Answer (score 0):

In class Dental, replace this:

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Dental{
    public Vector Sroomlist;
    public String name;
```

by this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Dental {
    public List<Sroom> sRoomList;
    public String name;
```

Also replace:

```
public Dental(String name, String address, int contact){
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.contact = contact;
    Sroomlist = new Vector();
}
```

by

```
public Dental(String name, String address, int contact) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.contact = contact;
    this.sRoomList = new ArrayList<Sroom>();
}
```

Also replace

```
public void addsrooms(Sroom room){
    Sroomlist.addElement(room);
}
```

by

```
public void addsrooms(Sroom room) {
    Sroomslist.add(room);
}
```

and finally in method "Details()" *sigh* replace

```
  int n = 0;
  while (n<Sroomlist.size()){
      Sroom room = (Sroom)
      Sroomlist.elementAt(n);
      n +=1;
      
 }
```

by

```
int n = Sroomlist.size();
```

That should make class Dental work and remove linter warning. It does however not improve the code's quality.